# Strange behavior of printk in linux kernel module

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, printk

I am writing a code for linux kernel module and experiencing a strange behavior in it. 
Here is my code:

```
int data = 0;
void threadfn1()
{
    int j;
    for( j = 0; j < 10; j++ )
        printk(KERN_INFO "I AM THREAD 1 %d\n",j);   
    data++;
}

void threadfn2()
{
    int j;
    for( j = 0; j < 10; j++ )
        printk(KERN_INFO "I AM THREAD 2 %d\n",j);
    data++; 
}
static int __init abc_init(void)
{
        struct task_struct *t1 = kthread_run(threadfn1, NULL, "thread1");
        struct task_struct *t2 = kthread_run(threadfn2, NULL, "thread2");
        while( 1 )
        {
        printk("debug\n"); // runs ok
            if( data >= 2 )
            {
                kthread_stop(t1);
                kthread_stop(t2);
                break;
            }
        }
        printk(KERN_INFO "HELLO WORLD\n");

 }
```

Basically I was trying to wait for threads to finish and then print something after that.
The above code does achieve that target but WITH `"printk("debug\n");"` not commented. As soon as I comment out `printk("debug\n");` to run the code without debugging and load the module through insmod command, the module hangs on and it seems like it gets lost in recursion. I dont why printk effects my code in such a big way?

Any help would be appreciated.

regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the call to `printk()` removed the compiler is optimising the loop into `while (1);`. When you add the call to `printk()` the compiler is not sure that `data` isn't changed and so checks the value each time through the loop.

You can insert a barrier into the loop, which forces the compiler to reevaluate `data` on each iteration. eg:

```
while (1) {
        if (data >= 2) {
                kthread_stop(t1);
                kthread_stop(t2);
                break;
        }

        barrier();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're not synchronizing the access to the data-variable. What happens is, that the compiler will generate a infinite loop. Here is why:

```
  while( 1 )
        {
            if( data >= 2 )
            {
                kthread_stop(t1);
                kthread_stop(t2);
                break;
            }
        }
```

The compiler can detect that the value of data never changes within the while loop. Therefore it can completely move the check out of the loop and you'll end up with a simple

```
 while (1) {}
```

If you insert printk the compiler has to assume that the global variable data may change (after all - the compiler has no idea what printk does in detail) therefore your code will start to work again (in a undefined behavior kind of way..)

How to fix this:

Use proper thread synchronization primitives. If you wrap the access to data into a code section protected by a mutex the code will work. You could also replace the variable data and use a counted semaphore instead.

**Edit:**

This link explains how locking in the linux-kernel works:

http://www.linuxgrill.com/anonymous/fire/netfilter/kernel-hacking-HOWTO-5.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe data should be declared volatile? It could be that the compiler is not going to memory to get data in the loop.

Comment: volatile would somewhat work, but it is always a bad idea because you can't make sure that data++ is an atomic instruction. On a multiprocessor system with multiple threads fighting for the same variable this will give you a guaranteed race-condition.

Answer (score 0):

Nils Pipenbrinck's answer is spot on. I'll just add some pointers.

[Rusty's Unreliable Guide to Kernel Locking](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/rusty/kernel-locking/index.html) (every kernel hacker should read this one).

[Goodbye semaphores?](http://lwn.net/Articles/166195/), [The mutex API](http://lwn.net/Articles/167034/) ([lwn.net](http://lwn.net) articles on the new mutex API introduced in early 2006, before that the Linux kernel used semaphores as mutexes).

Also, since your shared data is a simple counter, you can just use the atomic API (basically, declare your counter as atomic_t and access it using atomic_* functions).

Answer (score 0):

Volatile might not always be "bad idea". One needs to separate out
the case of when volatile is needed and when mutual exclusion
mechanism is needed. It is non optimal when one uses or misuses
one mechanism for the other. In the above case. I would suggest
for optimal solution, that both mechanisms are needed: mutex to 
provide mutual exclusion, volatile to indicate to compiler that
"info" must be read fresh from hardware. Otherwise, in some
situation (optimization -O2, -O3), compilers might inadvertently
leave out the needed codes.