# Using printf() changes multithreaded outcome?

Tags: c++, c, pthreads, printf

I'm writing a multithreaded program to run a modified bubble sort for a class project. Basically, each thread bubble sorts a segment of an array of integers, and each segment shares one element with its neighboring segments in order for values to flow between them. Currently, I am using `pthread_mutex_t`s around critical sections; but I must have something wrong, because sometimes it finishes sorted, sometimes it finishes not sorted, and sometimes the program just hangs.

**Here's my problem**: If I use `printf()`s to see where I am in each thread, it's virtually guaranteed to *not* hang (which makes it difficult to figure out where it's getting hung up). So why does using `printf()`s in certain sections of code run by each thread seem to prevent hanging and cause the program to finish?

**Edit**: I determined that the main cause of my issue was that I had not properly initialized my mutexes (with `pthread_mutex_init()`). So [chrk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2304215/chrk) was correct that I was using improper synchronization, and the `printf()` usage slowed things down enough to make it look like some things were working.

Comment: Use a debugger rather than `printf()` or post some code, else the question is too broad.  There are many potential reasons why including changed code will allow a program to run.   IMO some UB.

Comment: No Code, No answer-  but what you could be experiencing is some sort of Race Condition in which adding any line of code (printf for example) can change the timing of your code.

Comment: @chux, I'm not familiar with "UB" (a brief google search proved unhelpful). I'm playing around with gdb right now (trying to learn how to use it for this).

@NiRR, this question is more about trying to find out if there is something special about `printf()` that would cause this (I know the function is "thread-safe," so I didn't know if that affected things in an "interesting" way).

Comment: UB = Undefined behavior.

Comment: @chux, thanks--I read that wrong and thought you were suggesting a debugger called UB ;)

Comment: Look at your program optimization. Sometimes compiler puts an infinite loop while optimizing a part of code where it thinks that variables are not being used. Using printf does not let compiler optimize a simple lopp into an infinite loop.

Comment: @JewelThief, interesting--I just removed the -o3 optimization and still have the issue (is that what you meant by optimization?).

Comment: yes. Try to look at some variable which you might consider making volatile. For example, a loop in thread may read while(a < 10), try declaring "a" as volatile because some times compilers can convert these kinds of loops in to infinite loop. Happened with me at least :)

Comment: @JewelThief, I do have a couple `while(true)` loops with `break`s in them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be sure about this, obviously, just saying my guess:

Theoritically, `printf(3)` uses the system call `write(2)` to `stdout`, which is a I/O procedure, thus is slower than rest parts of your code which are CPU calculations. So if you have some other synchronization problem, the time spent for `printf()` to execute could possibly by accident "fix" some instances of that problem.

However that's not a proper way to fix synchronization problems, so you have to check your code again to find the race conditions that are being resolved in a wrong way.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to address the heart of the question, which is whether or not there is something special about `printf()` that would explain this behavior. So perhaps it's nothing "special" and just a timing issue--that's what I wanted to confirm.

Comment: Also, multithread aware libraries tend to synchronize all input/output per FILE* handle.

Answer (score 0):

Long ago, I had a similar kind of problem. Hope it helps. I too had printk issues and I found out that complier was optimizing my code and converting my loop to while(1);.

[Strange behavior of printk in linux kernel module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113176/strange-behavior-of-printk-in-linux-kernel-module)

Comment: That's actually quite fascinating; however, if this were the issue, wouldn't I expect my program to hang every time instead of just some of the times?